# Beautiful soup find href

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to select just the href inside a specific tr tag.

Here is my code:

```
soup=bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
obj=soup.find(text="test545")
new=obj.parent.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.previous_sibling
print new
if new.has_key('href'):
    new=new['href'] 
    print"found!"
```

Here is the output:

```
<td headers="LINK"><a href="f?p=106:3:92877880706::NO::P3_ID:5502&amp;cs=tmX92fFLmToJQ69ZOs2w"><img border="0"  src="/i_5.0/menu/pencil3416x16.gif"/></a></td>
```

I want to just select the  link inside of the href.

Edit:

Thank you alecxe for the correct solution.

Solution-

```
soup=bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
obj=soup.find(text="test545")
td = obj.find_previous("td", headers="LINK")
link = td.a
print(link["href"])
```

Comment: You have code posted. Is it not working? Is it throwing errors? What errors? Please add more details.

Comment: Sorry Jeff, I thought it was clear from the output. There are no errors. The problem is that I want to get just the href value. In my code I thought that "new" should have an href key, but it didn't. Alecxe solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing a full HTML of the page including the relative location of the element with text="test545" and the desired link, would help to provide you with a more robust solution.

But, given what was posted in the question, you can just find the `a` element inside the `new` element:

```
link = new.a
print(link["href"])
```

where `.a` is equivalent to `.find("a")`.

---

Also try using the [`.find_previous()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous) to locate the `td` element from the `obj` element:

```
obj = soup.find(text="test545")
td = obj.find_previous("td", headers="LINK")
link = td.a
print(link["href"])
```