# Pandas and beautiful soup: print href instead of the value for a column

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

This is so similar to other posts on SO e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903941/beautiful-soup-find-href), i just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I want to scrape the box labelled 'activity' on [this](http://www.conoserver.org/index.php?page=card&table=protein&id=23) page, and I want the output to look like this:

[image]

So you can see the two main features of interest compared to the original webpage (1) combining multiple tables into one table, by just creating a new column if the column is not already seen and (2) I want to extract the actual href for that column as opposed to just the name e.g. 'Jacobsen et al' because I was to eventually extract the PMID value (an integer) from the href.

These are my two goals, I wrote this code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(23,24):
#    try:
        res = requests.get("http://www.conoserver.org/index.php?page=card&table=protein&id=" + str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
        table = soup.find_all('table',{'class':'activitytable'})
        for each_table in table:

            #this can print references
            print(each_table.a)

            #this can print the data frames
            df = pd.read_html(str(each_table))
            print(df)

            #how to combine the two?
```

Can someone tell me the correct way to print the href individually for each row of each table (e.g essentially so it adds an extra column to each table with the actual href?; so it should print out three tables, with an extra href column in each table)

Then I can try focus on how to combine the tables, I've just mentioned the ultimate goal here in case someone can think of a more pythonic way of killing two birds with one stone/in case it helps but I think they're different issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialise a final dataframe. Then as you iterate, store the `href` as a variable string then add that column to the sub table dataframe. Then you'll just keep appending those dataframes to a final dataframe:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Initalized empty "final" dataframe
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(20,24):
#    try:
        res = requests.get("http://www.conoserver.org/index.php?page=card&table=protein&id=" + str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
        table = soup.find_all('table',{'class':'activitytable'})
        for each_table in table:

            #Store the href
            href = each_table.a['href']

            #Get the table
            df = pd.read_html(str(each_table))[0]

            #Put that href in the column 'ref'
            df['ref'] = href

            # Append that dataframe into your final dataframe, and repeat
            final_df = final_df.append(df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Can i ask, when I run the above code, but I add at the end 'for index,row in final_df.iterrows(): print(row['ref']), it prints the one href (i.e. the first href observed in the table) for all of the entries. I was trying to debug this (you may have seen my earlier comment that I deleted when I thought I figured it out), would you have an idea on that? I guess it's because the href is being set per table instead of per row, that's what i was trying to fix.

Comment: correct the href is per table. However, I can;t debug the issue if I can't see how you implemented it.